# How to convert a bootable usb to a bootable microSD card

Tags: boot, usb, bootable-media, micro-sd-card

I just got a recovery flash drive for my tablet containing its OEM version of Windows 8.1. There is only one problem... The power input is located too close to the 1 and only usb port. The system recovery requires there to be an external power source for it to proceed but this is not possible.

However, the microSD card slot is located in a spot where the power cord can still be plugged in.

Is there a way to take this bootable usb key containing the OEM Windows 8.1 and turn it into a bootable microSD that can be used to repair my tablet?

Edit: Under boot options it has:
1.OS boot Manager
2.USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk
3.USB CD/DVD ROM Drive
4.Network Adapter

Comment: Does your efi / bios have the option to boot from microSD? I use win-to-flash to create bootable media, I've used a usb to microSD thumb drive. It could be win-to-flash would be able to use the internal microSD and make it bootable. Just a warning, I think win-to-flash comes with some spam things you have to skip.

Comment: See edit. To me it doesn't look like it's an option...

Answer (score 1):

[Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) is a great little open source tool that will allow you to do exactly what you are asking.  Its something to keep around in your toolbox just for a weekend project and its totally free.  (free as in beer AND speech) [Unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/) is also widely used to burn a variety of images.

Either way, you will need to walk into this with an existing ISO image from your usb drive which you can do with something like CDBurnerXP or ImgBurn.

TechnoCore is right though, your device will also need to allow you to boot from SD so you might want to check into that before spending all of this time.  It sounds like that would be a pretty major mistake for a tablet company to make and you might just be better off finding a small USB device.

Good luck!

Comment: So basically the ISO file is needed that was used to create the bootable usb in the first place? I don't see any ISO file on the usb

Comment: Also I though I'd mention that I solved the problem in a slightly different way. Ended up buying a Ian extention cable with a smaller input! I agree though very poor design choice on HP's part.